# how to fetch the text of a div using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How do i fetch the text within the div using `id` selector i.e `test@test.com` in this case  using jQuery.

```
<div class="g10 edit_trader" id="email_54">test@test.com</div>
```

the following code fetch the value `email_54`

`$('edit_trader').attr('id')`

i tried using

```
$('edit_trader').attr('id').val();
$('edit_trader').attr('id').text();
$('edit_trader').attr('id').html();
```

nothing works.

thank you..

Comment: You should've just googled a bit... this question has been made a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) is prefixed with `#`. So if you wanted to get the contents of an element with id = email_54 you could do this:

```
var text = $('#email_54').text();
```

And if you wanted to use a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) you should prefix with .:

```
var text = $('.edit_trader').text();
```

But of course in this case since you could have multiple elements with the same class you might get an array as a result.

Comment: the problem is id attribute is assigned dynamically so i cannot predict what will be id.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar, in this case you could use a class selector but obviously if you have multiple elements with the same class you will get an array.

Comment: aah man, i could have simply fetched it using `$('.edit_trader').text();` no need to use id attribute at all. thank you

Comment: $('.edit_trader[id]').text() or $('.edit_trader[id^="email"]').text() might be more effective.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#email_54').html();
```

That's what you want

or

```
$('#email_54').text();
```

or if you're trying to construct the ID then get the text then do this:

```
var fooID = $('edit_trader').attr('id');
var fooText = $('#'+fooID).text();
```

or if you have many elements then you will need to loop or use `.each()` like this:

```
$('.edit_trader').each(funciton(i){
    var fooID = $(this).attr(id);
    var fooText = $('#'+fooID).text();
    //do  stuff now that you have the text in fooText
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes have periods in front of them.  If the IDs are dynamic, call it with .edit_trader[id].  The [id] will check for elements with class edit_trader and an ID.  This is in case you have multiple elements with class edit_trader.  Also, if you know what the dynamic IDs start with, you could use [id^="email"], for example.

This should work:

```
$('.edit_trader[id]').text()
```

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/wTFbe/).